# ggplot legend / label change with various guides

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to change the labels of a legend on a ggplot where I have legends for 2 aes. 
With scale_file_manual, it works, but for one of the two legends only. I guess I should use "guides" that I already used to remove the titles and also remove legend for a 3rd aes, but I do not manage to do it.
Do you have a solution?

Here is my code :

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Nb))
p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Sandwich.min, ymax = Sandwich.max, fill = 'grey70',alpha=0.8)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Assiette.min, ymax = Assiette.max, fill = '#6495ED80',alpha=0.8)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Pizza, col = '#FF7F24')) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Sushis, col = '#228B22')) +
  labs(title = "Business lunch cost by number of participants",
       x = "Number of participants",
       y = "Price (Euros)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,20,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,300,50)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE, colour = guide_legend("  "), fill = guide_legend("  ")) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values=c('#6495ED80','grey70'),
    labels=c("Assiettes","Sandwiches"))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want a quick fix, this should work: add `+ scale_col_manual(values = c('#FF7F24', '#228B22'), labels = c("Assiettes", "Sandwiches"))` to your plot. But it might be better to reshape your data from wide to long.

Comment: @markus Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried to do so, but I get an error message "Error in scale_col_manual : could not find function "scale_col_manual". I will try reshaping the data.

Comment: My bad. It should be `+ scale_color_manual(...)`. Didn't test when I wrote that comment. Hope it helps.